# Ubuntu 16.04 Switch to Previous Workspace

Tags: 16.04, compiz, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I have just recently started using workspaces and I really enjoy them. I use one for my email, one for my mail client, one for messages, and so on. One thing that bothers me, though, is if I get a message I have a keystroke to take me right to that workspace, but none to take me back to the old one. I'd have to remember which workspace number I was in and use a key to go back to that specific number, which just isn't terribly realistic given how I work.

My question is: Is there a way to record last workspace you were on and then map a keystroke to that? I've searched around, but every answer I've found to anything even close to this has been "just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-arrow keys" which I feel really ruins the flow that workspaces can provide.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use Super+S to spread all workspaces and select the previous workspace. By the way, your requirement is quite interesting! This would actually improve User Experience. I don't think there is anything like this.

Comment: I know about using Super+S to go through all workspaces, which is what I'm currently doing, I'm just looking for a bit more of a seamless way to transition. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Jason Blockwave I also like your idea and instead of the workspace table i would prefer a sequential workplace selection as some other distros follow with just Ctrl + Alt + Left/Right to navigate.